# Como delegar manualmente um objeto em Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramação

Para entender melhor a meta-programação em Ruby eu gostaria de fazer um objeto, ao ser instanciado, delegar todos os métodos de um objeto passado como parâmetro. E sua classe passe á delegar os métodos que a classe do mesmo contenha.
Porém gostaria que os métodos de Objeto e Class,como: **send** e object_id, os quais posam causar erros caso alterado, sejam iguinorados

Eu pensei em algo como:

```
 def delegate_all
    delegate_instance if !@delegated
    delegate_singleton if !@@delegated
end
def delegate_instance
    ((@model.class.instance_methods-Object.instance_methods)-Class.instance_methods).each do |name|
            name = name.to_sym
            puts name.to_s
            self.class.send(:define_method, name){ |*args|
                method = @model.method name
                #if method.arity > 0
                    method.call args
                #else
                #   method.call
                #end        
            }
    end
    @delegated = true
end 
def delegate_singleton
    ((@model.class.singleton_methods-Class.singleton_methods)-Object.singleton_methods).each do |name|
        name = name.to_sym
        puts name.to_s
        self.class.define_singleton_method(name){|*args|
            name = name.to_sym
            method = @model.singleton_method name
            #if method.arity > 0
                method.call args
            #else
            #   method.call
            #end    
        }
    end
    @@delegated = true  
end
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como eu possa fazer isso?, mas também devo considerar métodos com parâmetros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais simples é trabalhar com o `method_missing`, assim:

```
class SimpleDelegator < BasicObject
  def initialize(obj)
    @obj = obj
  end
  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    SimpleDelegator.new(@obj.send(method, *args, &block))
  end
  def inspect
    "SimpleDelegator for #{@obj.inspect}"
  end
  def to_s
    "SimpleDelegator for #{@obj.to_s}"
  end
end

x = SimpleDelegator.new(3)
y = x+2
print y  #=> SimpleDelegator for 5
print y.class #=> SimpleDelegator
```

A vantagem de fazer assim é que não precisará saber quais são os métodos do objeto antes de criar o delegador, qualquer método não padrão será imediatamente repassado ao objeto delegado. Repare que usei a herança de `BasicObject` para ter a menor quantidade possível de métodos próprios da classe.

```
BasicObject.instance_methods
# => [:==, :equal?, :!, :!=, :instance_eval, :instance_exec,
#     :__send__, :__id__, :__binding__]
```

Mas note que nem mesmo estes métodos são **necessários** para a classe funcionar. Você pode tranquilamente definir assim:

```
class SimpleDelegator < BasicObject
  instance_methods.each {|m| undef_method m } # remove todo e qualquer método
  def initialize(obj)
    @obj = obj
  end
  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    SimpleDelegator.new(@obj.send(method, *args, &block))
  end
end

x = SimpleDelegator.new(3)
y = x+2
print y  #=> 5
print y.class #=> Fixnum (note que não deixou de ser um SimpleDelegator)
```

Comment: Eu implementei meu delegator desta maneira, porém quero delegar um model do Ruby on Rails, e gostaria de redenizar-lo como se fosse o modelo, ex: '<%= render my_presenter %>', alguma dica de como implementar o mesmo

Comment: Até onde vejo, não tem porque um delegador falhar em funcionar nesse caso. Qual o exato problema que você tem? (seria uma boa abrir uma nova questão sobre isso)

Comment: Resolvi alterando os métodos 'methods', 'instance_methods', 'singleton_methods' incrementando os métodos dos objeto delegado

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma solução para esse problema na stdlib chamada SimpleDelegator:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html